# Yahoo Finance YQL Only working sometimes

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am observing some really strange behavior.

Sometimes the following URL works, sometimes it just says "Connect Failure" No definitions found.

Is there a timeout? It might work 1 out of 10-15 times, I have tried waiting for 10minutes but it just keeps saying the same. Stability issues? Something I'm doing wrong? What's happening?

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Name,Symbol,LastTradePriceOnly,Volume,Change%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOGL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

Comment: It still seems super unstable. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: From where you're making this request `localhost`, for example? can you add more information? Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues with YQL (OpenGraph) - sometimes it works without a glitch, some other times I get continuous timeouts.